# Emacs ESS Cannot read history file /user/filepath/.Rhistory

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I installed R-3.3.3 recently on my Macbook when I try to launch R from emacs in the working directory with M-x R, screen just freezes and complaining cannot read .Rhistory

Answer (score 0):

download ESS from https://ess.r-project.org/index.php?Section=download

unzip the files and keep it application folder, add the following in .emacs file for creating one c-x c-f .emacs add the link and save

(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/bin/ess-16.10/lisp/")
(load "ess-site")