# Emacs cannot read history file

Tags: r, ubuntu, emacs, history, ess

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931946/emacs-ess-cannot-read-history-file-user-filepath-rhistory), I installed Emacs, ESS, and R in Ubuntu 18.04.

Everytime I open Emacs to work with R (either by `emacs -f R` in the terminal, or with `M-x R` inside Emacs), I get the message:

> Cannot read history file...

Is there a way to avoid such message? The answer to the question above cannot work, as I have nothing in `/usr/bin/ess-16.10/lisp/`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set your `ess-history-directory` to a read/writeable location like "~/.cache/" or set `ess-history-file` directly in your `ess-hook`. Is there a reason you aren't using the emacs package manager to install ESS?

You should be able to get by with a very minimal configuration file, probably located at ~/.emacs (to determine which init file was used from emacs <kbd>M-:</kbd>`user-init-file`). Create one in your home directory if necessary and add to that file the following (to save your ESS history in ~/.cache/)

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" "https://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(and (< emacs-major-version 26)
     (package-initialize))
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)

;;; R setup

;; install ESS if necessary
(unless (package-installed-p 'ess)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'ess))
(require 'ess-site)

;; ESS settings
(setq ess-history-directory "~/.cache")
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I am not that proficient with Emacs, so you will have to walk me through this a little bit, if you can... How to use the Emacs package manager to install ESS? How to set the ess-history-directory or the ess-history-file? Thanks!

Comment: @DaniCee ok, there is a basic init file.  I'd recommend referring to emacs' extensive documentation pertaining to configuration, etc.

Comment: I used the above .emacs file and Emacs got stuck in the config steps for like 4h, I just quit it and I am having to reinstall it...

Comment: reinstall what? this doesn't change emacs... You can just delete the .emacs file

Comment: I reset .emacs file to its original content, but now I get `ess-build-load-command is already defined as something else than a generic function` and cannot even use R at all...

Comment: I can't debug your config since I have very little info about your setup, but it sounds like there is a conflict with an older version of ESS you installed somewhere on you system and a newer version. A lot of functions have been made generic in newer versions of ESS (which you get with the package manager). When you install a package it doesn't change emacs, so you can just remove a package if there are problems, you don't need to reinistall emacs - although if you  have version older than 24.3 I would strongly recommend upgrading emacs.